# How would I re-render the list everytime the state changes for this text filter using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have updated this question with clearer and more concise code on 15/03/22.

I have a text filter and it filters an array (displaying a list) correctly if it matches something in the displayed list, but as the user deletes character by character the filter does not change. I need it to keep matching as the user delete's chars.

Here is the filter which is set as the onChange for the text field:

```
const [searchInputTitle, setSearchInputTitle] = useState<string>('');
const [filteredItemsArrayState, setFilteredItemsArrayState] = useState<IListItems[]>(props.requests);

 const searchTitles = () => {
        let filteredArrayByTitle: IListItems[] = [];
        filteredArrayByTitle = theRequestsState.filter((item) => {
            return item.Title && item.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInputTitle.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        });
        console.log(searchInputTitle, 'searchInputTitle');
        if (searchInputTitle && searchInputTitle.length > 0) {
            setTheRequestsState(filteredArrayByTitle);
            setIsFiltered(true);
        } else if (searchInputTitle && searchInputTitle.length === 0) {
            const AllItems = props.requests;
            let sortedByID: IListItems[] = AllItems.sort((a, b) => a.Id > b.Id ? 1 : -1);
            setTheRequestsState(sortedByID);
            setIsFiltered(false);
        }
    };

 <TextField
    onChange={searchTitles}
    value={searchInputTitle}
  />

 useEffect(() => {
            _onTitleFilterChange(null, searchInputTitle);
        if (isFiltered == true) {
            setFunctionalArea(null, null);
            setRequestingFunction(null, null);
        }
    }, [isFiltered, searchInputTitle]);
////////

<DetailsList className={styles.DetailsList}
   items={filteredItemsArrayState.slice((ListPage - 1) * 50, ((ListPage * 50)))}
 />
```

Can anyone see why the render is not updating on deletion of char and what I could use to do so?

Update: As I type a character into the search I can see it's finding the searched for char/word and also if I delete chars now it searches and finds actively, but as soon as I stop typing it reverts back to the original array of items.

Comment: Can you make a small codesandbox to illustrate the issue better ? Tbh I am not getting the error through this code. How is your onchange handled for the user input field ?

Comment: I've added the fluent ui textfield function. Hope that gives more of an idea?

Comment: try using controlled components https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: @omercotkd It is a controlled TextField

Comment: `value={searchInputTitle ? searchInputTitle : ''}`  this part got my confused. why are you checking `searchInputTitle`  and if it false you return empty string? you can just do this: `value={searchInputTitle}`

Comment: Yep changed that but it's still not filtering when chars are removed.

Comment: I've added some similar code which works perfectly on a class based component. I hope this gives you an idea of what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. Thanks for all your help.
The issue was the  `setIsFiltered(true);` in the title filter function. Other filters were running based on this line and these other filters were recalling the unfiltered list everytime a key was pressed. I removed this line and the issue was fixed.

I have come to realise that useEffect is almost completely mandatory on most of my projects and is React hooks are quite a departure from the original React syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to filter the array you give to the DetailsList so you never lost the data ..?

```
filteredItemsArrayState.filter(s => {
            if (searchInputTitle.length === 0)
              return true
            else
              return s.Title.toLowerCase().match(searchInputTitle.toLowerCase())
            }).map(....)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you make your answer a bit clearer and using the same code I have used?